# Need some help, running a console timer in C#, any ideas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since C# is being pretty cringe, I am asking for help on how to debug it based on the comments in the code. As a summary, I have a timer running in console (noob here, code copy-pasted or tutorial'd) and the numbers ONE and GO are running simultaneously, and I have not found a way to stop the timer after the intended result is reached, and help would be appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startTime = 4;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("timer", 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    void timer()
    {
        if (startTime > 0)
        {
            if (startTime == 3)
            {
                Debug.Log("THREE");
                startTime -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (startTime == 2)
                {
                    Debug.Log("TWO");
                    startTime -= 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("ONE");
                    startTime -= 1;
                    //Precent "ONE" and "GO!" from running simultaneously
                }
            }
        }

        if (startTime == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("GO!");
            //Fix "GO!" playing to console indefinetly after timer is finished
        }

        void Update()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: Don't require users to go to external sites - the link can become invalid, making the question not understandable. Also, it hampers SO's search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can **use the CancelInvoke** method by passing the method name to quotes as a parameter you can call it when startTime goes to 0. You can safly remove the Update Method

```
public int startTime = 3;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("timer", 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void timer()
{
    //go throw all the cases
    switch (startTime)
    {
        case 0:
            Debug.Log("GO!");
            CancelInvoke("timer");
            break;
        case 1:
            Debug.Log("ONE");
            break;
        case 2:
            Debug.Log("TWO");
            break;
        case 3:
            Debug.Log("THREE");
            break;
    }

    //substract - from time
    startTime -= 1;

}
```

### Or use this Coroutine

```
void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("timer");
    }
    IEnumerator timer()
    {
        //debug the time
        Debug.Log(startTime); //you can use the if statement do show it as text or use any humanizer **C# 101 series**
        startTime--; //here we substract 1 from time
        //we wait for 1s
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); 
        //if the time still >= 0 repeat
        if(startTime >=0)
            StartCoroutine("timer");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, and it fixed the infinite GO! problem, but I still have a problem of ONE playing at the beginning, then THREE, TWO, and vice versa, as well as GO! playing at the same time as ONE. Pastebin has been updated.

Comment: By pastebin has been updated, I mean that instead of the code embed, I have put a pastebin in place :)

Comment: I just fixed that, it's much cleaner. You can accept my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want
//if (startTime == 0)
else
{
Debug.Log("GO!");
//Fix "GO!" playing to console indefinetly after timer is finished
}

Comment: This would work, but Unity gives me about 5 errors when I try it, I will play around and give a follow-up comment in a few minutes.

Comment: It didn't work with anything I tried.